# ES6 module "Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying ES6 module in google chrome. I would like to launch an alert() (in an imported function) when i click on the button.

js/notification.js is well loaded but when I click on the button I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: createNotification is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):24) <- line of the button in index.html

index.html

```
<head>
    <script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="container">
       <button type="error" onclick="createNotification()">Create</button>
    </section>
</body>
```

js/main.js

```
import {createNotification} from './notification.js';
```

js/notification.js

```
export function createNotification(type){
    alert();
}
```

Comment: Which Chrome version you are using?

Comment: `error` is not a valid type for a `<button>`: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type

Comment: 63 (module should work since 61) and type is just for css, not sure it s good or not!

Comment: @artlessboy: It's not, it's invalid. :-) Instead, change the CSS to use a class and put that on the button instead (and then leave off `type` if you want a submit button, or change it to `"button"` if you want a non-submit button).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Functions used in `onxyz`-attribute-style handlers must be globals (it's one of the many reasons not to use them). Your function isn't a global, it's local to the module in which you're importing it. (Remember: Your main script is a module too; if it weren't, you couldn't use `import` in it.)

You could make it a global by assigning to a `window` property:

```
window.createNotification = createNotification;
```

but it would be **much** better to use modern event handling:

```
document.querySelector("#container button").addEventListener("click", createNotification);
```

[Live example on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aCInhLLbzTzSA6yeAxe7?p=preview), obviously will only work on cutting-edge browsers with module support.

---

Side note: As [Andreas points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535822/es6-module-uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-at-htmlbuttonelemen/48535864#comment84066961_48535822), `type="error"` isn't valid for `button` elements. Valid types are `button`, `submit`, or `reset`, with `submit` being the default. (I've changed it to `button` in the plnkr.)