# es6 - import all function from some js files without alias for create webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have many js files where have a more function.Something like that:

```
// first file
function name1(){...}
function name2(){...}
function name3(){...}
function name4(){...}
...
// ...second file
function name(){...}
...
```

And have an entry point where I want to import that module and concatenate all namespace for webpack bundling, but I can`t use

```
import * as alias from "modules/myModules";
```

cause in my HTML I have attributes onclick, where I don`t write alias. 
I need something like:

```
import { * } from "module/myModules"
```

What can I do in this situation? (Do I write alias in HTML, or is there a better idea?)

Comment: `many js modules what have a more function` Huh?

Comment: Sry maybe I bad  known terminology(English I know bad, how you can see ), I meant what I have over 10 js files with many functions
I'm editing it, maybe that better explains my problems!

Comment: You want to group the imported functions into an object?

Comment: First of all, your method declarations are missing an `export` keyword. I assume you *did* use ES6 named exports for your modules, right?

Comment: You cannot import identifiers with a wildcard into an ES6 module. You can however use the webpack bundler options to put the exports of certain modules in the global scope.

Comment: I want to concatenate some count of a namespace in one namespace and connect him to HTML file, using that webpack chunk.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this thread ([es6 - import all named module without alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573779/es6-import-all-named-module-without-alias)) and [MDN's import spec page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), there is no es6 syntax for importing all symbols without an alias.

Also, it is best practice to namespace your javascript. Good namespacing prevents hard-to-debug name conflicts between multiple imports.

Lastly, tag attribute-style handlers can only access global definitions. Per [es6-module-uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-at-htmlbuttonelemen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535822/es6-module-uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-at-htmlbuttonelemen), you can either add your function to the global scope or attach it through javascript like

```
document.querySelector("#container button").addEventListener("click", createNotification);
```

I would recommend that you have a dedicated module for binding events to your page. This will prevent UI manipulation from leaking into your logic.

Comment: You mean that the best way will change a name of the function in my HTML, right?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Shortly, no. It is better to bind through addEventListener. Thanks for asking for clarity

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
import "module/myModules";
```

it should add your file to bundle.