# Uncaught ReferenceError: "function" is not defined ES6 Modules

Tags: javascript, module

I'm trying to use ES6 modules but html doesn't seem to recognize my event.

```
export function weatherCardCreator() {
    const cardContainer = document.querySelector('.card-container');
    const localStorageCities = dbManipulator.readData('Cities');
    let weatherCards = localStorageCities && localStorageCities.map(
        (weatherCard, weatherIndex) => `
            <div class="card" onclick="renderWeatherOnOneCityOnClick(${weatherIndex})">
                <div class="card-halfwayup">
                    <div class="flex-left">
```

`export function renderWeatherOnOneCityOnClick(weatherItemKey)`

Comment: Try creating the function first and then exporting it at the end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 module "Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535822/es6-module-uncaught-referenceerror-function-is-not-defined-at-htmlbuttonelemen)

Answer (score -1):

You didn't provide your import statement, but with a single import you need to

```
import thingYouAreImporting from 'path-to-js-file-with-export';
```

in order to access it from another file.
For importing from a file with multiple exports,

```
import { thing1, thing2 } from 'path-to-js-file-with-exports';
```